# Rails remove time from datetime attribute and group

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a column DATENEW in my invoices table.

If in my view I use:

```
 <td><%= invoice.DATENEW %></td>
```

it shows:

```
2015-02-16 11:38:03 UTC
```

I need to display only year month and day.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`strftime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) to show only year, month and date.

`<%= invoice.DATENEW.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>`

And for grouping, first show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

These `Time` / `DateTime` methods also may come in handy:

```
at_beginning_of_month
at_beginning_of_day
at_beginning_of_year
at_beginning_of_week
at_beginning_of_hour
at_beginning_of_minute
```

Answer (score 0):

`.to_date` works as well.

```
[6] pry(main)> Time.zone.now.to_s
=> "2023-07-13 09:09:44 UTC"
[7] pry(main)> Time.zone.now.to_date.to_s
=> "2023-07-13"
```